# I broke remote access when configuring an AD-DS

Tags: active-directory, remote-desktop, remote-access

I bought a VPS and today is the first day. I admit that Im new on server administration and yay, I broke it on my first day.

The objetive of this question is to learn from my errors, dont wan't to break it twice.

I have a domain (domain.com) and I wanted to access my websites using the domain. the company of the VPS doesn't provide me any DNS so I was told that I needed an Active Directory Domain Service.

Ok, I picked up a guide, I configured a new forest, used my domain.com domain, said that is W2008R2 and clicked next until the wizard ended. Next, it configured a DNS service and rebooted the machine. Since that, I lost the remote access to my machine. It says that is powered off, without network or without remote access. The machine is on, I can see my IIS hello world.

So, what happened and how can I prevent that?

If is not much to ask: the AD-DS is needed just to redirect my domain to my IIS? Or Im wrong?

Comment: You've confused AD domains with internet domains.  They aren't interchangeable concepts here.  AD domain s are a authentication and configuration tool, while internet domaina and for name resolution.  No need to add AD to serve up web pages.  You need IIS for that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can run a DNS server on Windows (either the built-in or third party) without having an Active Directory infrastructure. In fact, unless you have a compelling need to have Active Directory I would recommend against it. (Personally, I'd use a third-party DNS provider with nice geographically distributed servers, etc.)

Promoting the machine to being a domain controller shouldn't have disabled RDP access, though. I'm at a loss as to describe what happened there, unless the VPS provider has somehow "customized" the load of Windows to act differently than stock Windows Server 2008 R2.

If I were in your position with your experience-level I'd probably start with asking the VPS provider to return the machine back to the default configuration. That ought to be something very easy for them to do.

If you can access RPC on the machine you could probably use the Remote Server Administration Tools to get RDP running again (though, realistically, you should block RPC from the Internet, along with all other unnecessary traffic in a production configuration).

Comment: Thanks for the response Evan (and uSlackr for the comment). I was told that I needed AD. the vps provider have reinstaled the Windows.I will try to no disturb them again :P About the DNS thing, I will make a new question :) For now, vote up + accept answer.